# IOS - when I make a new Objective C class, what will checking "made for iPad" option do?

Tags: ios

I am making a new Objective C class and it gave two options as check boxes:

1) Targeted for iPad
2) Make an XIB interface

What if I want to make an app that would work on both iphones and ipads? Can I do that or will I essentially need to re-do the app, so if I am testing it out on the phone first, I should not check that box? Or will that box just make things compatible with the iPad?

Also, for the XIB interface - its where I can place the ui elements, right? But can I place the UI elements on the button right from the storyboard?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, XIB interfaces, like storyboards, are where you can interactively drop the UI elements.  XIBs are a more primitive version of storyboards (which came in with iOS 5), but at the same time if you're working on a project with many hands and developers working on a single project, or lots of screens and view controllers (which would make for a very hefty & unwieldly storyboard), it may be worthwhile to stick with xib files.

If you select "Targeted for iPad", you may only get a storyboard sized for iPad-sized screens.

If you select "Make a XIB interface", your new class will be using xib files instead of storyboards.

Comment: ah I see, so if I want to do a storyboard, I should just make it without the xib file and not check the ipad checkmark, right? I am trying to figure out how to make the new controller screens show up on my existing storyboard.

Comment: I've also noticed that editing storyboards is hugely taxing on the CPU, so it quickly gets sluggish to do things once you add many elements.

Comment: The system will allow me to acceot the answer in 5 min and I'll accept your answer then :)

Answer (score 4):

As far as I know it will create XIB files for iPhone and for iPad screen sizes.

You don't need to make 2 apps, you can use 1 App logic for both and just change the views.

**Few notes**

1. This is one places were the MVC is important.
2. In the project summery on xcode you should mark the app as universal.
3. an other few lines that can help you are:

   ```
   + (BOOL)isDeviceAniPad {
       #ifdef UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM
         return (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad);
       #else
         return NO;
       #endif
    }
   ```

You can use this code to check the user device any time your code needs to perform different operations for iPhone and iPad.

An other option will be to create 2 Targets - one foe iPad and one for iPhone and let the targets share the same code.